# Parsing very large bz2 xml file (element by element) in java and python

Tags: java, python, xml

I have a 20gb bz2 xml file. the format is like this:

```
<doc id="1" url="https://www.somepage.com" title="some page">
text text text ....
</doc>
```

I need to process it to tsv file in this format:

```
id<tab>url<tab>title<tab>processed_texts
```

What is the most efficient way of doing it in python and java and what are the differences (memory efficiency and speed wise). Basically I want to do this:

```
read bz2 file
read the xml file element by element
for each element
    retrieve id, url, title and text
    print_to_file(id<tab>url<tab>title<tab>process(text))
```

Thanks for your answers in advance.

UPDATE1 (Based on @Andreas suggestions):

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader xmlReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(in);
xmlReader.nextTag(); 
    if (! xmlReader.getLocalName().equals("doc")) {
        xmlReader.nextTag(); }

        String id      = xmlReader.getAttributeValue(null, "id");
        String url     = xmlReader.getAttributeValue(null, "url");
        String title   = xmlReader.getAttributeValue(null, "title");
        String content = xmlReader.getElementText();
        out.println(id +  '\t' + content);
```

The problem is that I only get the first  element.

UPDATE2 (I ended up doing it using regex):

```
if (str.startsWith("<doc")) {
                id = str.split("id")[1].substring(2).split("\"")[0];
                url = str.split("url")[1].substring(2).split("\"")[0];
                title = str.split("title")[1].substring(2).split("\"")[0];
     }
else if (str.startsWith("</doc")) {
                out.println(uniq_id +  '\t' + contect);
                content ="";

      } 
else {
                content = content + " " + str;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** The answer below works well for parsing very large BZ2 compressed XML *documents*, however OP's XML file is not well-formed since there is no root element, i.e. it's an XML *fragment*.

The built-in StAX parser does not support XML fragments, however the [Woodstox XML processor](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/WoodstoxHome) supposedly supports this, according to this answer: [Parsing multiple XML fragments with STaX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10020874/5221149).

---

**Java Answer**

As answered in this question ([Uncompress BZIP2 archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322944/uncompress-bzip2-archive)), you need [Apache Commons Compress™](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) to read BZ2 files.

You would then use the built-in [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html) parser:

```
File xmlFile = new File("input.xml");
File textFile = new File("output.txt");
try (InputStream in = new BZip2CompressorInputStream(new FileInputStream(xmlFile));
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(textFile))) {

    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLStreamReader xmlReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(in);
    try {
        xmlReader.nextTag(); // Read root element, ignore it
        if (xmlReader.getLocalName().equals("doc"))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected root element, found <doc>");
        while (xmlReader.nextTag() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
            if (! xmlReader.getLocalName().equals("doc"))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected <doc>, found <" + xmlReader.getLocalName() + ">");
            String id      = xmlReader.getAttributeValue(null, "id");
            String url     = xmlReader.getAttributeValue(null, "url");
            String title   = xmlReader.getAttributeValue(null, "title");
            String content = xmlReader.getElementText();
            // process content value
            out.println(id + '\t' + url + '\t' + title + '\t' + content);
        }
    } finally {
        xmlReader.close();
    }
}
```

Fast and low memory footprint.

Comment: The solution gives me this error: Message: found: `CHARACTERS, expected START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT`. I tried various solutions based on yours, but I can only pasre the first doc element.

Comment: it might be easier even to just process it as a text with regex.

Comment: Oops, was missing `!` on the `if` statement. Also, if your XML is not well-formed, and is missing the root element, you'll get that error.

Comment: Also, regex is generally a very bad choice for parsing XML. XML formatting is way too complex for regex.

Comment: I have no root element. It throws me this error: `Expected root element, found <doc>`, removing that if and error message, gives me this error: Message: found: `CHARACTERS, expected START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT` which is related to not having the root.

Comment: Remove the line `xmlReader.nextTag(); // Read root element, ignore it` too, and you should be good, though `nextTag()` might fail at the end because the XML is not well-formed. That can be fixed by replacing the convenience method (`nextTag()`) with the underlying loops.

Comment: I did that the first try and I got `Message: found: CHARACTERS, expected START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT`. I'll show my update code in the question as update.